# Grammar for Arithmetic Expressions

Tags: parsing, grammar

I was assigned a task for creating a parser for Arithmetic Expressions (with parenthesis and unary operators). So I just wanna know if this grammar correct or not and is it in LL(1) form and having real problems constructing the parse table for this

```
 S  -> TS'
 S' -> +TS' | -TS' | epsilon
 T  -> UT'
 T' -> *UT' | /UT' | epsilon
 U  -> VX
 X  -> ^U | epsilon
 V  -> (W) | -W | W | epsilon
 W  -> S | number
```

---

*Precedence (high to low)*

```
 (), unary –
 ^
 *, /
 +, -
```

*Associativity for binary operators*

```
 ^ = right
 +, -, *, / = left
```

---

Comment: You'll need a few more line breaks before we can tell you! Try formatting that a bit.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it in LL(1) form?

To tell if the grammar is LL(1) or not, you need to expand the production rules out. If you can generate any sequence of productions which results in the left-hand-side appearing as the first thing on the right-hand-side, the grammar is not LL(1).

For example, consider this rule:

```
X --> X | x | epsilon
```

This clearly can't be part of an LL(1) grammar, since it's left-recursive if you apply the leftmost production. But what about this?

```
X --> Y | x
Y --> X + X
```

This isn't an LL(1) grammar either, but it's more subtle: first you have to apply X --> Y, then apply Y --> X + X to see that you now have X --> X + X, which is left-recursive.

Comment: I removed the left recursions and did the left factoring but can't construct a parse table for this :(

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing anything for unary plus operator. Try this instead...

V -> (W) | -W | +W | epsilon

Comment: I think he gets that with [S' -> +TS' | -TS' | epsilon], since [+TS'] reduces to [+UT'S'] --> [+U{epsilon}S'] --> [+VX{epsilon}S'] --> [+{epsilon}{epsilon}{epsilon}S'] --> [+S'].

Comment: I don't think so. As it implies unary plus has the same precendance as binary plus and that would be incorrect.